Should I connect the 4th wire
Wiring help
I had a Leviton Decora combination switch which broke. It was wired like below
4 sets of wires were coming from the wall.
1 from lights, 1 from the exhaust fan and 1 from circuit. I’m not sure what is the 4th one from. It was connected to one of the live screw on the decora switch along with the actual live which was connected to the other screw.
I replaced this switch with Topgreener dual tech humidity and motion sensor switch.
I connected one live to the black and other unsure live to the blue wire. But the lights didn’t work.
So, I checked with multi-meter and there was not current on the second live wire.
I connected both black and blue to the actual live with current and both fan and lights worked.
So, what can be the 4th set of wire be for?
Should I leave it disconnected or connect it with the other live?

Please post pics of the wires inside of the box, and pics of the old switch wired the way it was before you disconnected it. Without knowing more, I would assume that the additional wire(s) carry current downstream to a different device somewhere.

There usually is a good reason for wires being connected together.  Some rare times it is a mistake or something else was removed and not disconnected there, but this is rare.

If you want to find out what the 4th set of wires are for, leave them disconnected, and tell everyone else in the house to let you know if they come across lights or outlets that don't work.  Verify that anything important that runs unattended still has power.  Fridge, freezer, sump pump...

Your 4th,unknown set of wires, (cable), by your information was connected to the hot side of a dual (combination) switch.
That tells me that the black wires on the switch were both hot. The incoming hot from the breaker transferred power to the other (4th unknown) by the bridge between the 2 screws.  That may not be the optimal way to connect the wires for constant hot, but it worked.
Of course all the grounds get tied together and neutrals (white) get tied together.
The 4th cable is obviously for a downstream load.  You will need to hunt down what that is.  Labeling on the breaker box may give some clue.
